# tricky binary multiplication

Tags: binary, multiplication

I attempted to multiply binary 1111 as first input and 1111 as second input. When I multiply as usual I came across having to do the addition below I encounter having to carry the 1 with the three 1's which would mean 4 in binary with 2 bits. But that's impossible to represent 4 in 2 bits for this multiplication problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add multiple binary values, then you just carry whatever is left over after adding a column, regardless of how many bits you need to represent the carry.

It's just like doing the decimal add 99+99+99+99+99+99+99+99+99+99+99+99, when adding the least significant column, you end up with 108, so you carry 10 eventhough it's too large to fit in a single digit.

Likewise, if you add the binary 11+11+11+11+11 you end up with 101 when adding the least significant column, so you carry 10.

However, normally you only add two binary numbers at a time, as that lets you get away with using a single bit for carry.

Comment: Oh now I understand! Thanks guffa and starwing!

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is carry the numbers over another digit.

Take the scenario:
    11 
    +11
   +11

---

you would have 1001 as your answer because 4 in binary is 100. Simply carry over the 1s into the correct place.

Comment: The thing is, I am encountering a problem: carrying a 1 with three 1's below the carry when doing 1111 * 1111.

Comment: It should still work. To organize your thinking, try doing the sub sums of the carrys before doing the big sum. Of course, the cleanest way of doing it is to simply do only two subsums at a time. This eliminates the possibility of carrying something more than 2

Comment: Oh nice I got 11100001 as the product!